# Custom Dialogs in Visual Studio Code - Extension with JSON and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, call

I'm developing a syntax-highlighting-extension for a custom programming language in Visual Studio Code.

For that I use some .json files for the implementation of snippets, syntaxes, etc.

Is it possible to build custom dialogs in visual studio code for starting a 4-times for-loop which does something when you write the String "for(4)"  in the editor of visual studio code and push enter?

Is it possible to call JavaScript in a JSON File?
If yes - how does it work?

---

best regards,
Grpwski